# Using an if statement with dtype object in Pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read in a csv file using pandas. One of the columns is the name of a county (which is dtype object). What I want to do is the following

```
if df.county == 'CountyName':
    do stuff
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different method:

```
rows = df[df.county == 'CountyName']
# dostuff with rows
```

You can't compare a scalar with a Series hence the error you received

Example:

```
In [12]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({'county':['asdasd','asdasd','CountyName']})
df

Out[12]:
       county
0      asdasd
1      asdasd
2  CountyName

In [13]:    
rows = df[df['county'] == 'CountyName']
print(rows)
       county
2  CountyName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the result of your selection, it's a series of True/False values.  You can then use that to select the rows of your DataFrame.

The docs on indexing have a bunch of good examples (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

You can see how it works like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

╔════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║            ║     A     ║     B     ║     C     ║     D     ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2000-01-01 ║ 0.924531  ║ -2.390000 ║ 0.760337  ║ 0.530209  ║
║ 2000-01-02 ║ -0.995364 ║ 0.268086  ║ -0.906000 ║ 0.867882  ║
║ 2000-01-03 ║ -0.835369 ║ 0.350561  ║ 0.671791  ║ -0.404308 ║
║ 2000-01-04 ║ -0.731701 ║ 0.375686  ║ -1.653192 ║ -0.246772 ║
║ 2000-01-05 ║ -0.601097 ║ -1.533039 ║ 1.653372  ║ 1.389123  ║
║ 2000-01-06 ║ 0.908657  ║ -0.525116 ║ -0.321091 ║ 1.852013  ║
║ 2000-01-07 ║ -0.895419 ║ 0.020809  ║ -0.395710 ║ -0.298697 ║
║ 2000-01-08 ║ 0.258146  ║ 0.343302  ║ 0.275674  ║ -0.828965 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝

df.A > 0

2000-01-01     True
2000-01-02    False
2000-01-03    False
2000-01-04    False
2000-01-05    False
2000-01-06     True
2000-01-07    False
2000-01-08     True
Freq: D, Name: A, dtype: bool

df[df.A > 0]
╔════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║            ║    A     ║     B     ║     C     ║     D     ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2000-01-01 ║ 0.924531 ║ -2.390000 ║ 0.760337  ║ 0.530209  ║
║ 2000-01-06 ║ 0.908657 ║ -0.525116 ║ -0.321091 ║ 1.852013  ║
║ 2000-01-08 ║ 0.258146 ║ 0.343302  ║ 0.275674  ║ -0.828965 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

This is similar to how matrix-based languages like Matlab tend to work:  that your operations create a set of bits (0's and 1's) that you use as an index.  This is also why using more than one column uses the version of AND and OR that is more familiar in the context of bitwise operations:

```
df[(df.A > 0) & (df.B > 0)]

╔════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║            ║    A     ║    B     ║    C     ║     D     ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2000-01-08 ║ 0.258146 ║ 0.343302 ║ 0.275674 ║ -0.828965 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```